# Scrape Goodreads editions

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrape

I'm trying to get Goodreads editions starting from a list of ISBNS, but the code doesn't get them all and some of the "editions" are actually weird codes scraped from the page. Now that Goodreads doesn't have an API it is necessary to find some workarounds. The code:

```
def get_isbn():
    isbns = []
    return isbns


def get_page(base_url, data):
    r = requests.get(base_url, params=data)
    return r


def get_editions_details(isbn):
    data = {'q': isbn}
    book_url = get_page("https://www.goodreads.com/search", data)
    soup = bs(book_url.text, 'lxml')

    ed_item = soup.find("div", class_="otherEditionsLink").find("a")
    ed_link = f"https://www.goodreads.com{ed_item['href']}"
    ed_num = ed_item.text.strip().split(' ')[-1].strip('()')

    return ((ed_link, int(ed_num), isbn))


def get_editions_urls(ed_details):
    # Unpack the tuple with the informations about the editions
    url, ed_num, isbn = ed_details

    # Navigate to all pages for books with more than 100 editions
    for page in range((ed_num // 100) + 1):
        r = requests.get(url, params={
            'page': str(page + 1),
            'per_page': '100',
            'filter_by_format': 'Paperback',
            'utf8': "%E2%9C%93"})

        soup = bs(r.text, 'lxml')

        editions = soup.find_all("div", class_="editionData")

        with open(f"urls_files/{isbn}_urls.txt", 'a') as fp:
            for book in editions:
                item = book.find("a", class_="bookTitle")
                    rating = book.find_all("div", class_="dataValue")[-1].text
                    rating = re.sub(ws_ptrn, '', rating)
                    fp.write(f"https://www.goodreads.com{item['href']}" +
                             f"  rating: {rating}\n")
        # Let some time to the goodreads server between the requests
        time.sleep(2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        os.mkdir('./urls_files')
    except Exception:
        pass

    isbns = get_isbn()

    for isbn in isbns:
        ed_details = get_editions_details(isbn)
        get_editions_urls(ed_details)
```

Comment: What is the output, and what should be the output?

Comment: The output is a reduced number of editions (and a weird alphanumeric string sometimes when there is the language part). So if the actual editions on Goodreads are 500, it retrieves 200.

Comment: `ws_ptrn` is undefined in your code provided

Comment: it's a whitespace pattern

Comment: you are also missing the `except:` in your `get_page()` function

Comment: Oh, I cut it because thee was too many code for my text! I edited it

Comment: And your `get_isbn()` doesnt return anything in that list. You need to provide enough code to reproduce your issue. Doesn't need to be the FULL, but enough for us to run it.

Comment: give me a list of a few ISBNs that seem to give you an issue.

Comment: The mostly problematic ISBN is this: 9788845210662

Comment: create minimal working code with example data in code - so we could simply copy and run it to see problem and test solutions.

Comment: pages can be different and need different code - and you may need to use `if/else` to execute different code, or run one code and if it doesn't give result then run second code.

Comment: what is `editions` ? If you want to get all reviews then maybe you should search `reviews` instead `editions`. And I see in HTML `<meta itemprop="reviewCount" content="10459">`

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you get in variables - it finds `Other Editions (191)` so you have `~200` results.

Comment: it is safe to get link from `Next Page`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya it looks like it defaults to return number of editions for a certain type (not sure for which type though...it's saying 191...but Hardcover is 192). Regardless, your code sees that and says to only go through pages 1 and 2. You however query it to get Paperback which is 227 editions. So your code iterates through 2 pages, and returns only 200 of 227 Paperback edition.

[image]

Easiest way though to do this is don't hardcode the number of pages to go through. Just have it go to the next page until it runs out of editions to process (Ie put a `while` loop that continues until it gets to the last page...which in this case since you get 100 per page, once the page has less than 100 editions).

I also made it into a csv instead of a txt (was just easier for me to debug), but you can switch it back to txt if you'd like.

So this book has 227 Paperback editions, and as you can see, this returns 227:

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import os
import time
import re


def get_isbn():
    isbns = ['9788845210662']
    return isbns


def get_page(base_url, data):
    try:
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}
        r = requests.get(base_url, headers=headers, params=data)
    except:
        r = None
    return r


def get_editions_details(isbn):
    data = {'q': isbn}
    book_url = get_page("https://www.goodreads.com/search", data)
    soup = bs(book_url.text, 'html.parser')

    ed_item = soup.find("div", class_="otherEditionsLink").find("a")
    ed_link = f"https://www.goodreads.com{ed_item['href']}"
    ed_num = ed_item.text.strip().split(' ')[-1].strip('()')

    return ((ed_link, int(ed_num), isbn))


def get_editions_urls(ed_details):
    rows = []
    
    # Unpack the tuple with the informations about the editions
    url, ed_num, isbn = ed_details

    # Navigate to all pages for books with more than 100 editions

    end_of_list = False
    page = 0
    while end_of_list == False:
        print('Page: ', page+1)
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}
        r = requests.get(url, headers = headers, params={
            'page': str(page + 1),
            'per_page': '100',
            'filter_by_format': 'Paperback',
            # if you want all editions change above line to 'filter_by_format': '',
            'utf8': "%E2%9C%93"})

        soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')

        editions = soup.find_all("div", class_="editionData")
        
        print(len(editions))
        if len(editions) < 100:
            end_of_list = True
            

        #with open(f"urls_files/{isbn}_urls.txt", 'a') as fp:
        #    for book in editions:
        #        item = book.find("a", class_="bookTitle")
        #        rating = book.find_all("div", class_="dataValue")[-1].text
        #        rating = ' '.join(rating.split())
        #        fp.write(f"https://www.goodreads.com{item['href']}" +
        #                 f"  rating: {rating}\n")
        # Let some time to the goodreads server between the requests
        for book in editions:
            item = book.find("a", class_="bookTitle")
            rating = book.find_all("div", class_="dataValue")[-1].text
            rating = ' '.join(rating.split())
            row = {'item':f"https://www.goodreads.com{item['href']}",
                   'rating': f'{rating}'}
            
            rows.append(row)
        
        
        time.sleep(2)
        page += 1
    return rows


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        os.mkdir('./urls_files')
    except Exception:
        pass

    isbns = get_isbn()

    for isbn in isbns:
        ed_details = get_editions_details(isbn)
        rows = get_editions_urls(ed_details)
        df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
        df.to_csv(f"urls_files/{isbn}_urls.csv", index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
                                                  item                  rating
0    https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/119073.The...  4.12 (276,636 ratings)
1    https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10522.Il_n...    4.26 (7,445 ratings)
2    https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/71565.El_n...    4.26 (6,129 ratings)
3         https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/16082109      4.02 (968 ratings)
4    https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9269618-g-...    4.38 (1,429 ratings)
..                                                 ...                     ...
222  https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/58462415-t...         4.00 (1 rating)
223  https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/57406880-e...         0.0 (0 ratings)
224  https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/40944198-e...         0.0 (0 ratings)
225  https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/29927352-n...         0.0 (0 ratings)
226  https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/29242657-i...         4.00 (1 rating)

[227 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: I made similar code but I think there can be other problem - server may send different content to different browsers/devices. In browser I see ~560 links but code always get ~200.

Comment: now I realized that problem can be `format: Paperback` - without format it get `~500`, with format I get `~200` :)

Comment: Yes. The browser returns all types back (569, which is 227 Paperback, 192 Hardcover, 18 Mass Market Paperback, 23 Kindle Edition, 26 ebook,, 16 Audiobook, 9 Audio CD, 1 Audio Cassette, 5 Audible Audio, 2 MP3 CD, 8 Unknown Binding, 42 unclassified.

Comment: @furas, ya I don't know where it's getting the 191 from on the initial request though.

Comment: @furas and ya when I remove the filter by format, i get back 569.

Comment: maybe this was problem which OP mentioned in comment `"So if the actual editions on Goodreads are 500, it retrieves 200"` :)

Comment: @furas, good very well be. not really sure to be honest as that's what the post says, but not what the code says.

Comment: so what if I want all formats? Is it possible?

Comment: I put it in the code for you but commented out. basically change to `'filter_by_format': ''` instead of `'filter_by_format': 'Paperback'`